# Images do not appear using lazyload

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-lazyloading

I have an image gallery and I intend to load the images slowly as the scroll is made.

For that, I execute a function that sends the image path and in return I receive the image in base64.

I tried to simulate in the stackblitz, but the images do not appear to me, and the function is being executed.

What is the reason why the images don't appear, coming from the function's return?

Can someone help me?

Library used:**ng-lazyload-image**

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejwlnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list first">
    <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngFor="let image of Images; let i = index">
        <img [lazyLoad]="image.url">
        <div class="mdc-image-list-supporting"
            style="display: flex; align-items: center;flex-direction: column;padding: 2px">
            <span class="mdcImageListLabel">{{image.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Function**

```
export class LazyLoadImageHooks extends IntersectionObserverHooks {
  loadImage({ imagePath }: Attributes): Promise<any> {
    console.log(imagePath)
    return fetch(imagePath, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ...',
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then((blob) => URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }
}
```

**Problem --> Images do not appear**

[image]

I intend that the images are returned by the function and not directly from the * ngfor of the Images object.

Comment: if you check the Network tab you would see that requests are being made. Something blocks images(cors related?). Change your img source to some different and you would see it